# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Desktop Freezes on startup without acpi=off

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia, freeze, acpi

I just managed to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my new custom built PC. However, there's still one problem.

When booting, the computer freezes on the purple screen if `acpi=off` is not added after `quiet splash` in grub. I have previously tried `nomodeset` but it kept freezing and the only remedy was to add `acpi=off`. Now I have installed the proprietary graphics drivers for my Nvidia card. However, I can only use 1 core now and the system has some issues on shutdown. I assume those are due to acpi?

How can I fix this issue?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here are the full specs for my build:

```
Motherboard: asus tuf gaming x570-plus (wi-fi)
CPU: amd ryzen 7 3700x with stock cooler
GPU: Nvidia RTX3070
SSD: 1 TB Samsung Evo 970
RAM: 16 GB DDR4 Hyperx Fury
```

Comment: Hi Highness! You have very new hardware, but are using an older Ubuntu release. Please try out Ubuntu 20.10 or 20.04 LTS, these versions are newer and incompatibilities with your hardware might therefore already be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried updating to the newest version using ```sudo do-release-upgrade``` and I get the error: "Grub failed to install to /dev/nvme0n1p1. Writing GRUB to boot device failed. "

Comment: When dealing with an already defective install it's often best to completely reinstall. Try booting from a 20.10 or 20.04 USB and start a reinstall from there. Make sure you have backups of important data!

Comment: I should mention that I have tried multiple times to reinstall from a USB. Everytime I get the same error in case of 20.04. For 18.04 I never got the GRUB error. The freezing problem appeared in both (even before the installer loaded) so I always had to add ```acpi=off```